# How to redirect/render to 404 if the "_id" is wrong/misspelled in /blogs/:blogId

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to redirect users to "404.ejs" if the post id is entered wrong/mispelled in blogs/:blogId route. How can I accomplish it in below code.

```
app.get('/blogs/:blogid', (req, res) => {
   const requestedId = req.params.blogid;

   Blog.findById(requestedId, (err, addedblogpost) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        else {
            res.render("post", {
                title: addedblogpost.blogTitle,
                content: addedblogpost.blogContent
            })

   
        }
    })

}
```

Code for "404"

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.render('404');

})
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make use of express next parameter to get the result you want.

This will call the next "matching" middleware for the current route, assuming this would be your error handler middleware of course.

It should be used as shown below :

```
app.get('/blogs/:blogid', (req, res, next) => {
    const requestedId = req.params.blogid;
 
    Blog.findById(requestedId, (err, addedblogpost) => {
         if (err) {
             next();
         }
         else {
             res.render("post", {
                 title: addedblogpost.blogTitle,
                 content: addedblogpost.blogContent
             })
 
    
         }
     })
```

Express doc : https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html

Answer (score 0):

```js
app.get('/blogs/:blogid', async (req, res) => {
   const requestedId = req.params.blogid;

   const blog = await Blog.findById(requestedId);
   if (!blog) return res.render("404");
   res.render("post");

}
```

to check if the blog is null or not.